# Use Google URL Shortener in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url-shortening

I would like to use the Google URL [Shortener](http://goo.gl/) in Google Chrome. Has anyone figured out or heard of a way to do this yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is their [release announcement](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/making-urls-shorter-for-google-toolbar.html), it is only available for Google Toolbar and Feedburner. And to quote the post

> If the service proves useful, we may
>   eventually make it available for a
>   wider audience in the future.

With all that said, I did find this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fdndabnoclcmkbdgakdhdpjghagfnapj) for chrome

Comment: http://goo.gl/jqoL

looks like it worked

Comment: Here is a better extension though: http://goo.gl/PiyX

Comment: Als found this URL, which does it through a regular page for those not using chrome http://gaigalas.net/lab/googl